# update contents of shiny UI based on change of input value

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shiny-server

I have the following in ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  uiOutput("test"),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
  tabPanel("Test",conditionalPanel("input.show==1",includeHTML("index.html")))
  )
    )

))
```

and the following in server.R
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

```
  output$test <- renderUI({
      tmp <- readLines("www/termite.css")
      ifelse(grepl("#ccc",tmp[2]),tmp[2] <- gsub("#ccc","#FFF",tmp[2]),tmp[2] <- gsub("#FFF","#ccc",tmp[2]))
      write(tmp,"www/termite.css",sep = "\n")
      tmp <- readLines("index.html")
      tmp[8] <- gsub("This is a page","This is my page!",tmp[8])
      write(tmp,"index.html",sep = "\n")
      checkboxInput("show","change bg color",value=0)
  })

})
```

And in index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hi there</title>
  <link href="termite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
  This is a page
  a simple page
</body>
</html>
```

In www/termite.css

```
body {
 background-color: #FFF;
 cursor: default;
}
```

Now the server program will update the termite.css file after the program executes. And only when checkbox is selected "index.html" should be loaded on ui. but now the ui loads the existing file and it wouldn't update it again. I tried returning 'includehtml' function from server, but it's not loading all the external files. It is loading external files only when called from ui. Here initially color code is #FFF, so when I select checkbox it should load page with background color #ccc and the text should be changed to "This is my page!"
Thanks in advance.

Comment: a reproducible example would be most helpful here

Comment: In general, when you need to make something dynamic in Shiny, you need reactives. The [Shiny tutorial](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/) has a section on it.

Comment: @Paul. Yes. when I want something dynamic I can use reactive in server.R. But my problem is with loading html along with js in shiny. when i use includehtml it opens the connection at the launch of ui but not after I select the input.And uiOutput, htmlOutput are not loading the needed external files to return from server.